# install mysql 5.6 on centos6.4 conflicts error

Tags: mysql, centos6.4

When i try to install mysql 5.6 and i remove mysql 5.1 from centos

now not installing any mysql in my VPS.

```
yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * extras: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * updates: mirrors.gigenet.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.1.73-3.el6_5 for package: mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts MySQL-server
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql-server conflicts with MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@jg58 man1]# yum install mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * extras: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * updates: mirrors.gigenet.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package         Arch             Version                  Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql           x86_64           5.1.73-3.el6_5           base           894 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 894 k
Installed size: 2.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/mysql_config from install of mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-devel-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-devel-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/my_print_defaults from install of mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

and mysql ststus is:

```
grep -i mysql
MySQL-embedded-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-devel-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to already have MySQL-devel-5.6 and MySQL-server-5.6 installed as per the output from yum - you can either proceed to use those packages, or to get back onto the repo-maintained packages (as you seem to be attempting to do), remove those packages manually before re-trying the installations via yum.

If you wish to manually remove the currently-installed versions as above, you could try `rpm -e MySQL-devel-5.6` and `rpm -e MySQL-server-5.6`, although if I were you I'd be asking myself why I already have these software versions installed if trying to install from repositories.

Comment: `rpm -e MySQL-devel-5.6
error: package MySQL-devel-5.6 is not installed`??

Comment: Try using wildcards then (if you wish); `rpm -e MySQL*` or alternatively `yum remove MySQL*`

Comment: no :( . i tray many way to fix it and cannot fix my problem!!!

Comment: What is your output for `rpm -qa | grep -i mysql` ? Please update the original post with the output.

Comment: OK yes, you are showing several MySQL related packages installed; use the above `rpm -e` commands on each to remove them individually before proceeding (with the possible exception of the perl package)

Comment: My problem fixed by using `rpm -e ` to all packages .add all commented methods to your answer for other users and i will accept your answer! but when i tray to install again and after install mysql it not runnig correct and show message `Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.`